# How to find executed query by user

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I want to find all the queries executed by an particular user in a database over a period of time in MYSQL. Even they executed query by using MYSQL workbench i want to see log in my Database cloud server. Is there any possible there in MYSQL.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of MySQL?  Do you have an 'audit' or 'authentication'  plugin installed?

Comment: i have used MYSQL 5.6 version and it installed centos 6.5.

Comment: If you have not turned on the "general log", nor have any type of auditing plugin, then the information you request is not available.